# Similar Logos - stolen or not?

Tags: logo, plagiarism

A friend asked me to develop a logo for his wife's hair salon. Originally I worked with just text, but she said she definitely wanted scissors as part of the logo, so I built in the the H + D (hair daun) in to the scissors but originally mirrored so that when the girls has the logo on their uniforms, the logo would then appear correctly. So we went for the normal look.

Today, however, a local business in their hometown has told them that I have stolen the logo from his site, made a few minor adjustments to make it appear as if it is a custom logo.

I had no idea the company existed until an hour ago, and I am really confused as to where the comparison has come from.

**My Logo**

[image: my logo]

---

**Supposed Stolen Logo**

[image: supposed stolen logo]

Comment: Maybe you should ask them. It's not as if you are even using the same font.

Comment: i did, he said it is so plain to see that he thought the question was an insult.

Comment: ... then admit you're an idiot and you are not seeing it. Ask to point out 5 similarities. (I can see 2, but only in a fairly wide sense: sans serif fonts, flat design. Who else is he going to accuse of copying that – Microsoft? Apple? Google?)

Comment: cheers... will do.

Comment: Are these the two logos? I don't understand how they are the same at all, other than both use a rather similar (but common) type treatment.

Comment: I agree with @DA01 .. I would not call these logos similar at all. I do not see how *anyone* could think of them as similar.

Comment: At this point, millions of logos are "copied" from this "Schalt Werk" logo!  You can simply ignore what the guy says and don't waste your time proving your design is original. No court will ever see anything copied from the other logo. If he has issues, he can send his lawyer's letter and pay for this, he really has nothing to gain from doing this though. There's pretty much ZERO infringement. By the way, your logo is really smart and well done! Good work you did there!

Comment: All I can really stat is there are [a lot of companies](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1179&bih=1397&q=gear+logo&oq=gear+logo&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1060.2201.0.2402.9.8.0.1.1.0.167.701.1j5.6.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..2.7.705.AxGuMR7CNs0) that should be contacting Schalt Werk :)

Comment: As they're both local... could it be that there is something else behind that, some sort of personal feud?

Comment: Haha. Ridiculous. Hard to even say where he is coming from by calling them similar.

Comment: What is your question here? The titular question is something you can answer yourself, because you know that you did not steal the logo. The body does not contain an explicit question.

Comment: There is ZERO similarity. The owner of that company is just a greedy selfish a**hole who wants to rip you off. If I were you, I'd tell him that. And IF he would sue you (he won't) there is no way he can win.

Answer (score 12):

There are not that many similarities. Both images are "flat design" and have a white background.(1) Both use a muted color. Both use sans serif fonts. The same is true, more or less, for [Windows 10](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/windows-10-a-closer-look-at-its-design/), [Mac OS X Yosemite](https://bold.pixelapse.com/minming/mac-os-x-yosemite-under-the-magnifying-glass), and [Google's UI guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html).

Let's see about the differences then. I think these are the most obvious:

[image: differences]

(where possibly "different font" depends on if one would state with confidence "surely these are the same fonts", i.e., *font blind*).

(1) .. here but not where used on the respective websites. The HAIRDAUN logo is entirely transparent, the SCHALTWERK is partially transparent, partially white.

Comment: I would go as far as saying there isn't any notable similarity.

Comment: @Terry You couldn't say better. It takes longer to note what's different than was is similar. Besides being done (probably) in Illustrator, I can't see what's similar! And his logo has some similarity with the old Pepsi logo by the way teehee!

Comment: I was thinking on how to make one design animate into the other but figured it was just too much work! It would not have been so if they were more alike.

Answer (score 2):

The only answer is:

## Not

If anyone has a different opinion, he/she has to explain it. Over and out.   It is not your job.

BTW: I like your logo :)

Comment: While in general stackexhange favors bit more meat this is a instance where this is enough, in fact anything more may be hiding the answer. Personally i can only think theres some communication misunderstanding, because theres no way in hell these two are close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY similarity is that they are both illustrations. Anything beyond that is pure imagination. I think it's just a case of design envy! Keep up the good work! ~dh

Comment: Hi Les Bruno! Welcome to GD.SE. We follow a strict Q&A format (as opposed to a forum format), so I'm afraid your answer might get some down-votes because it doesn't really bring anything new to the other answers. You can visit our [help] to read more about how the site works. Don't get discouraged, though! We have a lot of un-answered questions that would greatly benefit from some input!

Answer (score 0):

Both are completely different, I cannot see where it has been stolen..

One thing I do see that was 'stolen' or share similarity is the 'Supposed stolen logo' with Pepsi logo..

Maybe its his work process to to steal logos, so now he is projecting his insecurity onto you.